# GraphQL - Syntax error: expected ":", found ")"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-server

I am working on a project using GraphQL with some basic queries and mutations.  I have set up the typeDefs and resolvers in the same format as I have in the past, and mostly expect the same result.  However, when I try to start my server, I get the below error.  So far I have cut queries and mutations out of my typeDefs one at a time, as well as commented out resolvers one at a time with no effect.  I've perused the error locations, but haven't been able to really find any information that would point me to the area or even file that this syntax error exists.  Any help would be super helpful!

```html
$ npm start

> crm-tools@1.0.0 start E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server
> node server.js

E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1413
    throw (0, _syntaxError.syntaxError)(this._lexer.source, token.start, "Expected ".concat(getTokenKindDesc(kind), ", found ").concat(getTokenDesc(token), "."));
    ^

GraphQLError [Object]: Syntax Error: Expected ":", found ")".
    at syntaxError (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\error\syntaxError.js:15:10)
    at Parser.expectToken (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1413:40)
    at Parser.parseInputValueDef (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:912:10)
    at Parser.optionalMany (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1503:28)
    at Parser.parseArgumentDefs (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:900:17)
    at Parser.parseFieldDefinition (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:880:21)
    at Parser.optionalMany (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1503:28)
    at Parser.parseFieldsDefinition (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:868:17)
    at Parser.parseObjectTypeDefinition (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:812:23)
    at Parser.parseTypeSystemDefinition (E:\Coding_Bootcamp\projects\CRM-Tools\server\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:708:23) {
  locations: [ { line: 53, column: 25 } ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! crm-tools@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crm-tools@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shawn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-02T03_23_00_391Z-debug.log
```

**/typedefs.js**

```html
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

// create our typeDefs
// TODO timecard formatting?
const typeDefs = gql`
type Employee {
  _id: ID
  firstName: String
    lastName: String
    street: String
    city: String
    state: String
    zipcode: Int
    email: String
    phone: String
    timeCards: [Int]
}  

type Client {
    _id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    street: String
    city: String
    state: String
    zipcode: Int
    email: String
    phone: String
    workOrders: [WorkOrder]
  }
  
  type WorkOrder {
    _id: ID
    date: String
    description: String
    notes: [String]
    parts: [String]
    invoice: String
    timeClocks: [Int]
  }

  type Warehouse {
    parts: [String]
    laborItems: [String]
  }
 

  type Query {
    me: Employee
    employees(_id: ID): [Employee]
    employee(_id: ID!): Employee
    clients: [Client]
    client(_id: ID!): Client
  }

  type Mutation {
    addEmployee(Employee): Employee
  }
`;


// export the typeDefs
module.exports = typeDefs;
```

**resolvers.js**

```html
const { Client, Employee } = require('../models');

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        // get all clients
        clients: async () => {
            return Client.find()
            .populate("workOrders");
        },

            // get single client
        client: async (parent, { _id }) => {
            return Client.findOne({ _id })
            //.populate("workOrders");
        },

        // get all employees
        employees: async () => {
            return Employee.find()
            .populate("timeCards");
        },

        // get single employee
        employee: async(parent, { _id }) => {
            return Employee.findOne({ _id })
            .populate("timeCards");
        }
    },

    Mutation: {
        addEmployee: async (parent, args) => {
            const employee = await Employee.create(args);
        }
    }
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of the code you've tried.

Comment: Apologies, typedefs and resolvers have been added into main question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition for the mutation is incorrect, it needs a variable before the type:

```
type Mutation {
  addEmployee(employee: Employee): Employee
}
```

You can validate the syntax of your graphql via a graphiql plugin, or this [publicly available one](https://lucasconstantino.github.io/graphiql-online/).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was searching for something around that line 53, so I never thought to check the syntax of the mutations. It is fixed and running now.

Comment: Glad to hear it!